# LCD TV as VGA Monitor does not go widescreen

Tags: windows-7, display, tv, vga

My PCs graphics card is a VIA UniChrome Pro III. The TV is a Digistar 27 inch LCD and supports a 1280 x 800 resolution.

Under *Screen Resolution* in Windows 7, I can choose 1280x800 and 1280x768, but both result in the TV going to 1024 x 768. However if I set the resolution to 1280x1024 the TV gets set to this.

What could be wrong? Why does it refuse HD resolutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you SURE the TV supports that resolution?  I googled it a bit and the max resolution seems to be [advertised as 1366 x 768](http://www.quebecannonce.com/jeux-video/tv-27-lcd-digistar-widescreen-hdmi-no27792.htm) (aka 720p), with 1080i and p downscaled to 720p.

If 1366x768 is not an available option when you go to select the wanted resolution, then you may want to figure out what VIA chipset is on your motherboard (as the S3 Unichrome Pro video is part of the VIA chipset) and then go get the latest drivers from VIA or your motherboard manufacturer, as it may/will add those extra resolutions (if the UniChrome supports them at all).